# vbscript, using counting variable to identify other variables

Tags: variables, loops, vbscript

I have variables el1, el2,....el16 and c1, c2,....c16 and Counter
Would like to use in a counting loop

```
For Counter = 1 to 16
  If el1 = "x" Then
    el1 = 0
    c1 = 0
  Else
    c1 = 1
  End If
Next
```

The If statement works fine with defined variables.  How can I combine the "Counter" variable with the "el" and "c" in the loop to recognize as el1, c1, el2, c2,...el16, c16

### Here is the final version of the script.  It worked fine in Windows 7 version of ArcPad, but the If statement blew up on the mobile device using mobile vbscript runtime libraries. The variable array method might work better, but I wasn't quite sure how to patch it in. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub findelement
Dim el1, el2, el3, el4, el5, el6, el7, el8, el9, el10, el11, el12, el13, el14, el15, el16, scoreA, scoreB, calc

el1 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element1")
el2 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element2")
el3 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element3")
el4 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element4")
el5 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element5")
el6 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element6")
el7 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element7")
el8 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element8")
el9 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element9")
el10 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element10")
el11 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element11")
el12 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element12")
el13 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element13")
el14 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element14")
el15 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element15")
el16 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element16")

Dim c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15, c16, Counter

For Counter = 1 to 16

If "x" = eval ("el" & Counter) Then
    execute "el" & Counter & " = 0"
    execute "c" & Counter & " = 0"
Else 
    execute "c" & Counter & " = 1"
End If
Next

'do math
scoreA = CInt(el1) + CInt(el2) + CInt(el3) + CInt(el4) + CInt(el5) + CInt(el6) + CInt(el7) + CInt(el8) + CInt(e9) + CInt(el10) + CInt(el11) + CInt(el12) + CInt(el13) + CInt(el14) + CInt(el15) + CInt(el16)
scoreB = CInt(c1) + CInt(c2) + CInt(c3) + CInt(c4) + CInt(c5) + CInt(c6) + CInt(c7) + CInt(c8) + CInt(c9) + CInt(c10) + CInt(c11) + CInt(c12) + CInt(c13) + CInt(c14) + CInt(c15) + CInt(c16)
calc = CDbl(scoreA) / CDbl(scoreB)
'vbscript assumes these are strings and appends them, to get the sum like you want cast them to a double (CDbl) or integer (CInt)
'MsgBox (scoreA)
'MsgBox (scoreB)
'MsgBox (calc)

'Return calculated data to form.....
EDITFORM.Pages("Results").Controls("sumEl").Value = (scoreA)
EDITFORM.Pages("Results").Controls("scoreB").Value = (scoreB)
EDITFORM.Pages("Results").Controls("calc").Value = (calc)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [`ExecuteGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342311f1%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [`Eval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to dynamically form variable names for expressions to execute:

```
Execute "el" & Counter & " = 42"
```

Comment: Thanks, but having trouble inserting that in the If statement

Comment: More specifically, the If statement is asking if an "x" was input in the form rather than an integer.  It appears that Execute works to declare the values on following lines, but the first line, If eval "el" & Counter & = "x" Then, gives error complaining about 'Then'

Answer (score 1):

In general, Eval/Execute/ExecuteGlobal are dangerous, inefficient, and
unnecessary. There are exception (e.g. library/module import, (quick and dirty)
calculations based on user input), but I doubt that your (real) problem can't be
solved without such Voodoo.

Compare:

```
  Dim el1, el2, el3
  el1 = "a"
  el2 = "x"
  el3 = "b"
  WScript.Echo "el:", el1, el2, el3
  Dim c1, c2, c3
  Dim i
  For i = 1 to 3
      If "x" = Eval("el" & i) Then
         Execute "el" & i & " = 0"
         Execute "c" & i & " = 0"
      Else
         Execute "c" & i & " = 1"
      End If
  Next
  WScript.Echo "el:", el1, el2, el3
  WScript.Echo " c:", c1, c2, c3

  output:
    el: a x b
    el: a 0 b
     c: 1 0 1
```

(idea stolen from Helen)

With:

```
  Dim sEL  : sEL      = "a x b"
  Dim oWAN : Set oWAN = WScript.Arguments.Named
  If oWAN.Exists("el") Then sEL = oWAN("el")

  Dim aEL : aEL = Split(sEL)
  WScript.Echo "aEL:", Join(aEL)
  ReDim aC(UBound(aEL))
  Dim i
  For i = 0 to UBound(aEL)
      If "x" = aEL(i) Then
         aEL(i) = 0
         aC(i)  = 0
      Else
         aC(i)  = 1
      End If
  Next
  WScript.Echo "aEL:", Join(aEL)
  WScript.Echo " aC:", Join(aC)

  output (no arg):
    aEL: a x b
    aEL: a 0 b
     aC: 1 0 1

  output (arg: /el:"a a a x b x x c x"):
    aEL: a a a x b x x c x
    aEL: a a a 0 b 0 0 c 0
     aC: 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

I think, you'll agree that using a collection/array gives you as much flexibility
as the eval/execute approach.

Comment: Thank you both Helen and @Ekkehard.Homer.  I have a workable solution.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Homer - Could you take another look.  I had it working fine until I tried it on a mobile device, then the eval statement didn't work.  I'd like to try the variable array you mentioned, but wasn't quite sure how to fit it in. Thanks